# Menu not shown in GTK applications

Tags: gtk, menu

The menu bar is hidden for all my GTK applications (LXTerminal, Leafpad, Thunar...). How can I show it? I have the issue with OpenBox, and with Gnome-shell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on OpenSUSE 42.3 with GTK 2.0 appplications. When searching for a solution I often stumbled upon `unity` and on ubuntu forums there is a [post that states this is a unity bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar).

As I do no use unity, I tried removing related packages. For me the packages to remove were  `unity-gtk2-module`, `unity-gtk3-module` and `unity-gtk-module-common`. Removing these packages solved my problem. All menubars were back after the next login.